# Clojure AND / OR of Sets

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

```
(defn GetValuesFromWhereCommand
    "return a list of values from Where command"
    [Query tableName]
    (let [values (re-seq #"[0-9a-zA-Z_=<>]+" ((re-find #"WHERE(.*)" Query) 1))
        bitwise (re-find #"AND|OR" Query)
        tempList (ref #{})
       ] 
   ; first loop will look for the operators  = < >
   (doseq [item values]
    (let [result (case (re-find #"[=><]" item)
        "=" (GetRowsfromCondition tableName item = )
        "<" (GetRowsfromCondition tableName item < )
        ">" (GetRowsfromCondition tableName item > )
        nil (println "nothing")
     )]
     (when (not= nil result) (dosync (alter tempList conj result)) )
    tempList)
   )
   (println tempList)
   tempList)     ; get the Where from Update ','
)
```

here is my output.

```
#<Ref@5a4e229e: #{#<Ref@3fc2e163: #{0}> #<Ref@63280c85: #{0 1}>}>
```

i would like to make implement AND operation that will return #{0}
 and OR that will return #{0 1}.

my problem is how to access the lists i have created. I wasn't able to use union/intersection for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should deref all the inner sets and apply union to the new set
it should look somthing like this:

```
(let [newList (ref #{})] (doseq [item @your_ref_to_set_of_refs] (dosync (alter newList conj @item))) (apply union @newList))
```